# Ошибка (OSError: [WinError 123]), из за чего возникает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import time

#Откуда копируем
source = ['"D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"']

#Куда копируем
target_dir = '"D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive"'


#Название папки с сохраненым архивом резервных данных, в формате: 
#%Месяц%День%Год
today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')

#Создание имени zip-архива в формате %Час%Минута
now = time.strftime('%H-%M')


#Если в целевой папке нет каталога, создаем его
if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)

print('Идет процесс создания архива резервных данных, пожалуйста подождите...')


#Присваиваем имя архиву
target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'


zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Архив резервных копий успешно создан в', target)
else:
    print('Создание архива резервных копий НЕ УДАЛАСЬ')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вижу что ругается на 20 строку,  даже знаю как это исправить, изменить имя папки с `Backup Archive` на `BackupArchive` то есть убрать пробел, тогда все заработает, только вот у меня вопрос, по каким причинам так происходит, ведь в коде все в порядке, путь где есть пробелы нужно писать в `""`, это сделано, так почему происходит ошибка? И как можно было бы её обойти что ли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, дело в следующем:

- Сначала посмотрим на `target_dir`. Когда вы к этому пути ещё что-то пристыковываете, то наличие кавычек внутри строки "ломает" путь - по правилам кавычки должны быть в начале и в конце пути с пробелом, а после того, как вы что-то пристыковали в конец такой строки, кавычки оказались внутри пути, а не по краям, и получился неправильный путь. Кроме того, у команды `os.mkdir` нет проблем с пробелами внутри пути - она ведь получает параметр-строку, в которой нет ничего, кроме имени каталога, поэтому для неё не нужно обрамлять каталог с пробелом дополнительными кавычками, для неё вся полученная строка - это имя каталога, и не важно - есть там пробелы или нет. Таким образом, внутренние двойные кавычке в самом `target_dir` не нужны. Но поскольку вы потом используете полученный из него `target` в командной строке - в момент формирования командной строки с `zip` кавычки придётся добавить вокруг значения `target`.
- Теперь посмотрим на `source`. Пути, содержащиеся в этом списке, добавляются внутрь командной строки, в которой вызывается команда `zip` с параметрами и там уже без кавычек, обрамляющих путь к каталогу, утилита `zip` никак не сможет понять - где начинается и где кончается путь с пробелом внутри, поэтому в этом случае кавычки обязательно нужны. Хотя их тоже можно было бы добавить уже в момент формирования командной строки.

`"D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive"\2020.10.26` - это кривой путь, получающийся в результате соединения пути с кавычками с другим путём

`zip -qr "D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive\file.zip" "D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"` - как тут разобраться без кавычек, где что начинается и где кончается?

В общем, в вашем случае я бы добавил кавычки в `target` уже в момент формирования командной строки с `zip`, ну или сразу перед этим. Но не ранее того. Например, можно сделать так:

```
zip_command = 'zip -qr "{0}" {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

И ещё тут нужно упомянуть, нормальный способ конкатенации путей каталогов - это через `os.path.join`, но и туда тоже лишние кавычки передавать не надо, он их правильно не состыкует, если они есть.

Comment: Вас понял, а что делать в том случае, если требуется для `target_dir.` указать путь с пробелом? тип:`target_dir = 'D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive'`? Если писать в таком виде, он сохраняет архив по пути `D:\Miscellanea` а не в папку `Backup Archive` и если есть возможность покажите на примере как добавить кавычки в `target` в момент формирования командной строки с `zip`

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Добавил пример. Можно было заэкранировать кавычки, но я поменял внешние на другие, обратите внимание

Comment: Обратил, спасибо за ответы большое, но я все еще не понимаю как обходится с пробелом в пути `target_dir = 'D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive`

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Перечитайте ещё раз что я написал про `target_dir`. Сначала там внутренние lдвойные кавычки лишние не нужны. Кавычки для `target` нужны только при формировании команды `zip`.

Comment: Добваление в `zip_command = 'zip -qr "{0}" {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))` кавычек исправило положение, все работает корректно, правильно ли я понял, что кавычки в `source` нужны были только для правильного понимания пути, командной строкой `zip`, а в случае `target_dir`нет в них необходимости, так как её значения передаются в `os.mkdir` у которой нет проблем с пробелами?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Да, всё так. Вы гораздо короче сформулировали то, что про что я накатал два скрина текста ))

Comment: Я немного опешил когда выяснилось что так можно `zip_command = 'zip -qr "{0}" {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))` всм просто поставить кавычки, теперь буду знать, спасибо большое)

Comment: Есть последний вопрос, я немного не улавливаю ход скрипта, почему если не выставлять в `zip_command = 'zip -qr "{0}" {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))` кавычки всм `"{0}"` то архив сохраняется по пути `D:\Miscellane` а не как положено в `D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive`? Ведь в конечном итоге если не ставить там ковычки то создается путь `D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive\\%m.%d.%Y\\%H.%M.zip "D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"` можно было подумать что скрипт стопориться на моменте пробела, а именно `D:\Miscellanea\Backup` и сохраняет в предыдущем каталоге архив так как не нашел папку `Backup`?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Тут я сразу не соображу. Вы на печать выдайте что в `zip_command` получается, может что-то понятнее станет.

Comment: Понимаю, тогда большое спасибо что помогли разобраться, пойду копаться дальше)

Answer (score 1):

```
#Откуда копируем
source = ['"D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"']

#Куда копируем
target_dir = '"D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive"'
```

вы очень щедрый на кавычки человек :)

простой пример:

```
path = 'd:\\in put.txt'

fin = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
print(fin.readlines())    
fin.close()
```

Comment: Черт, правильно ли я понял, что в случае кортежей допустимы только одинарные скобки типа```'...'```или ```"..."```, и только со списками возможно писать типа ```['"..."']``` ? В любом случае когда я изменил ```'"D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive"'``` на ```"D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive"``` все заработало.

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Да нигде не надо писать лишние кавычки

Comment: @Анатолий Михеенко, нет, у вас есть пусть `D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive`, который вы записали в строку - все замечательно, но зачем вы к этому пути добавили еще пару кавычек? функции работы с путями начинают ругаться на такие пути, аналогично с `source` - массив из 1 пути- замечательно, но опять в пути записаны кавычки, которые функциями работы с путями не воспринимаются. Поэтому просто уберите `""` или `''` - это уж как вам больше нравится

Comment: @Zhihar В книге по которой я учу питон пишется, что в случае если присутствуют пробелы в пути, требуется ставить дополнительные кавычки ```"..."```, кстати код ```source = ['"D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"']``` из книги списан точь в точь, правильно ли я понимаю что в этом случае тоже лучше использовать только одинарные кавычки типа ```source = ["D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"]```

Comment: @Анатолий Михеенко, всегда можно проверить на простом примере, привел его в конце ответа. Может вы не так поняли, что имелось в виду? даже когда файл из нескольких слов никаких дополнительных кавычек не надо, а вот если их поставить - появляются ошибки

Comment: @Zhihar Я вижу что код работает, хочу понять просто нюанс, прикрепил скрин из книги в вопросе, возможно что я действительно что то не так понял, поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко А в книжке как эти значения потом используются? Возможно, не так, как увас

Comment: @CrazyElf Только что перепроверил и прикрепил скрин полного кода из книги, все используется в дальнейшем как в книге

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Ага, ну вы видите, что в `target_dir` нет вторых кавычек? А в `source` есть, да. Тщательнее надо )

Comment: @CrazyElf  Вижу, судя по комментарием кода в книге, в `source` есть двойные кавычки так как там в пути присутствует пробел, вот и возник вопрос, почему если в пути `target_dir` Есть тот же пробел, то кавычки ставить не надо, я выдвинул предположение выше, что первое мол список, а второе кортеж, но это опровергли, сказав что двойные кавычки в принципе без надобности

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Вы просто смотрите, как это всё потом используется. Когда вы к этому пути ещё что-то пристыковываете, то наличие кавычек ломает путь с одной стороны, а с другой стороны для `os.mkdir` дополнительные кавычки не нужны. А вот если вы скармливаете путь в командную строку, в которой вызываете `zip`, то там уже без кавычек внутри строки он не сможет разобраться где начинается и где кончается путь с пробелом.